# Can I do this in pure CSS instead of using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Currently, I'm setting width and height of some elements with jQuery in window resize event, based on `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`.

Something like this:

```
$(".gr1").css("height", (window.innerHeight - 150) + "px");
```

And these are some other examples:

```
$(".gr2").css("width", ((window.innerWidth / 2) - 12).toString() + "px");
$(".box1").css("height", ((window.innerHeight - 150) / 3 - 12).toString() + "px");
$(".box2").css("height", ((window.innerHeight - 150) / 2 - 12).toString() + "px");
```

And this is rendering a little slow in Chrome 21 (Windows) and renders too slow in iPad and Nexus 7 tablet. (Since there are many elements with `gr1`, `gr2`, `box1` and `box2` classes)

Can I do this in Pure CSS to give better performance? How?

Comment: Please show us your DOM. Are the elements unique, which styles do they already have?

Comment: @Bergi My DOM is messy, also it has many other things. Anyway, I'll post a link to it in a few minutes. But, Why you need DOM?

Comment: Why would a mechanic need a car to see what's wrong with it? "My car has a problem, here's a description of it, now fix it!"

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi: There is no layout with nothing to display. What are these elements you want to resize, where are they in your page? Only their contents is irrelevant

Comment: Maybe if you would optimized your selectors the performance would be satysfactory. This may be possible - but depends on your DOM and/or usecase.

Comment: There are quite a few things you could do to improve the performance of what you already have. By the looks of it each time you are calling the resize event you are re-searching the DOM for all the elements you want to change, again and again. First off, save this list to a variable. i.e. `$gr2 = $('.gr2');` and then inside your resize function access using `$gr2.css('width', ...);`. Better still don't use jQuery for a simple operation as setting width or height. Use something like `var i = $gr2.length, h = (window.innerWidth / 2 - 12) + "px"; while(i--){$gr2[i].style.height = h;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using [**`calc()`**](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-values/#calc), but [the support is not very good](http://caniuse.com/calc) (limited to IE9+, FF4+, Safari 6, Chrome 19+ & Firefox for Android).

Test: http://dabblet.com/gist/3609183

Comment: No. As I've said in my answer, it only works in IE9+ and FF4+.

Comment: Yup, tested it now, it also works in Chrome. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Without seeing your HTML or CSS I can't give you a definitive answer, but the best solution if you need the elements of your page to react to the browser window being resized is to use % widths, combined with `min-width` and `max-width` to set concrete size limits.

Comment: If it was `.css("height",(window.innerHeight / 3))`, I could use percents. but there is an extra `+ 12` or `- 150` in the height. How do I implement these with percents?

Comment: Yep, the normal way to do this in CSS  would be to create a fluid layout.

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi to get the +12/-150 use `margin` to amend the width.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I didn't understand what you said. Can you make a simple example code and make a link to it in your answer?

Comment: Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/R4PCb/ resize the browser window to see it in action.

Comment: In your example, width of boxes are `25%` and `50%`. How to have a box with width `25% - 20px` or `window.innerWidth / 4 - 20`) for example?

Answer (score 4):

you could try to cache your jQuery selectors, improve performance:

```
var gr1 = $('.gr1');
var gr2 = $('.gr2');
var box1 = $('.box1');
var box2 = $('.box2');
$(gr1).css("height", (window.innerHeight - 150) + "px");
$(gr2).css("width", ((window.innerWidth / 2) - 12).toString() + "px");
$(box1).css("height", ((window.innerHeight - 150) / 3 - 12).toString() + "px");
$(box2).css("height", ((window.innerHeight - 150) / 2 - 12).toString() + "px");
```

Comment: I have tried this, but still slow... It is just a little slow on my Windows PC, but too slow on iPad...

Comment: remove the toString(), use mathRound()

Comment: Are you defining the vars outside of your resize function? because if not you are not making any saving...

Answer (score 2):

[Media Queries](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/mediaqueries) Would possibly be the way to go, though it depends on your definition of "Pure" CSS, as media queries are new to CSS3, and don't work [fully in IE 6/7/8](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries).

If you don't know, they work by only applying certain styling based upon the screen/devices current resolution. You can see an [example](http://www.responsivewebdesign.co.uk/), resize the window and see how the content changes?

This is referred to as [responsive web design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design)