# Set correct line height to avoid clipped text

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a `div` with `overflow:hidden` which is showing a *multiline* text, and **I want to avoid clipped text.**

Here is an example of a clipped text:

[image: Example of a clipped text]

And I want to do this in Pure CSS. (No Javascript)

If I have fixed height for my `div`, I can use `line-height` for this purpose, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yDHUB/3/).

But, my `div` has `height:50%`... So, How to show *multiline* text as much as possible in my `div`, and also avoid text clipping?

**Edit:** Currently, I'm using [dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) ellipsis javascript plugin, also I have tested another plugin (I don't remember what the name was); but They are too slow, especially when there are many boxes to apply ellipsis to, and especially on iPad and Android tablets. (They are much faster in Chrome for Windows)

Comment: What happens with `line-height: 50%`? (I'm not able to test it myself right now).

Comment: Do you know the number of lines and the text-size?

Comment: @Abody97 No. Also the font has not fixed-width characters...

Comment: @HenrikAmmer Text becomes sloppy. And `line-height:100%` is usual (with text clipping)

Comment: Question updated. Please read the update.

Comment: To my knowledge this is not doable in just CSS. However, it shouldn't be that a big deal with some Javascript calculations and even tablets and phones should have no problem with it. It's all about, knowing the line-height of the type and then see if the containers height can be split without modulus with the line-height. If not, change the height.

Comment: But, even just changing the size of boxes is slow on tablets. see my other problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248212/can-i-do-this-in-pure-css-instead-of-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Set the height of the #text div in your example to 100%. It then uses the full height and displays the maximum of text in the div #container.

See this fiddle: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yDHUB/4/)

Comment: And, I don't want to set the height of #text to 100%... It should be for example 50% in my layout...