# Why Bootstrap use Javascript instead pure CSS?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm newbie to Bootstrap 3, but I noticed that Bootstrap require Javascript even if it's not necessary, e.g. dropbown menu doesn't work if js is disabled. Is there any good reason to prefer js over CSS?

Comment: Maybe because of portability?

Answer (score 1):

I think cause Javascript and CSS are different and can't replace each other.
In CSS you can't do for example calculations, DOM manipulation, react on click and other live events. Javascript can't style your HTML, have media queries etc. see also: [Performance: Pure CSS vs jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675952/performance-pure-css-vs-jquery)

Yes, i know there are alternative for everything, see:

[Can I do this in pure CSS instead of using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248212/can-i-do-this-in-pure-css-instead-of-using-jquery), [Can I have an onclick effect in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/onclick-in-css), etc .... but it is not the same.

What's your problem with javascript? in the first place? Do you have some requirements like: "should work with javascript disabled". Should your site work with this requirement or should it be exactly the same. What are you alternatives for javascript disabled? basic CSS? full css3? For me it seems realistic to prevent errors with javascript disabled but not expect all work the same. In the case of a dropdown you could consider a alternative navigation structure.