# On input focus change color of label. How?

Tags: less

On input `focus` I want to change the color of the label element. How can I achieve this in less?

```
.control-label{
      color: @gray-light;
}
.controls{
  input,
  textarea{
    background-color:red; 
    &:focus{
      .control-label &{
        color: red;  //HERE
      }

    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Firstname</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Firstname">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't think you can without changing your HTML, see also: [Is there any way to hover over one element and affect a different element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867257/is-there-any-way-to-hover-over-one-element-and-effect-a-different-element), your elements should be direct siblings. (LESS don't help to solve your problem here, LESS generate CSS and it seems impossible to do in CSS)

Possible suggestion:

```css
input:focus + .control-label
{
    background-color:purple;
    color: red;
}
.controls > input
{
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="controls">
    <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Firstname">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Firstname</label>
</div>
```

Or solve your problem with javascript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20226218/1596547

Answer (score 32):

One solution would be to use the `:focus-within` selector.

So, you'd do something like the below. Assuming that you always have an input of some description inside of a `control-group`, it will style the label whenever the input is focused on.

```
control-group {
    &:focus-within {
        control-label {
            color: red; 
        }
    }
}
```

More information can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It does the job without messing with the ordering of elements.

Comment: With almost complete (no IE) browser support, this is excellent. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Saved me a lot of work and restructuring! Also better readable than the alternatives - Thx!!

Answer (score 11):

#### Use Flexbox

CSS is cascading, i.e. affected by the order that elements appear in the DOM. To be able to select the label only when the input is focused (`input:focus + label`), the `label` needs to come after the `input`, so;

Put the `input` before the `label` in the DOM and then use flexbox to reverse the order that they appear on the page.

```css
.input-group {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

input:focus + label {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <input value="Input" />
    <label>Label</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

One solution would be to move the `label` below the `input` in the DOM but position them absolutely (to the parent) so the `label` looks to be above the `input` field:

```
<div>
  <input type="text"/>
  <label>Text</label>
</div>
```

In CSS move the `label` to the top, the `input` to the bottom:

```
label {
  position: absolute
  top: 0
}

input {
  position: absolute
  bottom: 0
}
```

And use the `:focus` state to change the style of the `label`:

```
input:focus + label {
    color: red
}
```

See example:

http://codepen.io/robcampo/pen/zGKLgg

On focus, the `label` turns red. No JS required.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I am not too late to answer this. With the new `:has` psudo-class we can achieve it without changing the HTML,

HTML:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Firstname</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Firstname">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.control-group:has(input:focus) label{
 color: red;
}
```

This approach is simple and cleaner.

**Note: it is not supported by firefox yet.**

Comment: I think this is the most accessible solution as screen readers prefer labels to appear before inputs in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

```
control-group {
    &:focus-within {
        control-label {
            color: red; 
        }
    }
```

}

loads of hearts to this person. Nothing was working and this worked in ion-label too . Accepted answer. Stack overflow does not allow to comment (below 50 reputation). So writing seperately <3

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to use :focus-within [check developer mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)

```
.control-group:focus-within .control-label {
   color: red;
}
```

Or

```
.control-group:focus-within label {
   color: red;
}
```